# Resizing table not possible when using tinymce control

Tags: javascript, tinymce

We are using TinyMCE 4 and our users are annoyed that you cannot take a table within the tinymce textarea editor drag its width and height and change it.  It appears this is not possible with tinymce.  The only way you can adjust the table is by going to the menu selecting table and modifying values for width / height in pixels.  Most of our users don't even know what a pixel is.

I tried using a plugin that someone wrote for TinyMCE 3.3 
http://sourceforge.net/p/tinymce/plugins/163/

But this plug in does not work for TinyMCE 4, nor do I understand how to modify this plug in to make it work for 4.0.  Someone asked here quite recently (wasn't me) but got no response:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=34454

Whats currently happening in chrome is when you try to grab a corner of the table and drag and drop it never drops, nor does it ever release the table.  It ends up in a state of confusion...you basically cannot release the drag of the table it keeps getting bigger and smaller as you move your mouse - but you can never let go and release it to get the size you want.

The only other option I am finding is to disable resizing, but this would disable resizing for everything:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:object_resizing

Is there any way around this?  We are using the TinyMCE 4 main package and not the jquery package if that helps.

Comment: funny it works for me in chrome using there example.
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: Wow you are right, the obvious never hit me, why in the world didn't I just update...It seems to be working..Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been alot of bugs with TinyMCE and chrome it's why i now use CKEditor but apparently the bug your on about has been fixed in 4.1 so update your tinyMCE version and it should work for you.

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Another point is that if you looked at the documention you provided you can allow resizing for anything but tables.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:object_resizing

> This options allows you to turn on/off the resizing handles on images,
>   tables or media objects. This option is enabled by default and allows
>   you to resize table and images. **You can also specify a CSS3 selector
>   of what you want to enable resizing on**.

```
tinymce.init({
        ...
        object_resizing : "img"
});
```

Could be

```
tinymce.init({
            ...
            object_resizing : ":not(table)"
    });
```

Comment: Is there a post mentioning this as a bug?  Updating to the new version seemed to work!

Comment: nope but i know back on 3 i had masive problems with chrome and AJAX submitting a form with TinyMCE re initializing tiny MCE and it still would not work

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead (redirects to the TinyMCE homepage).

Comment: @KarlRichter Thats because TinyMCE Version 3 has EOL'ed you should be using 4.X https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/advanced-editing-behavior/#object_resizing